How Can i solve this "Try signing in with a different account." problem with Next-Auth?
This is my route.ts ,
I am using these libraries:

"@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
"@prisma/client": "^5.4.1",
"prisma": "^5.3.0",
"next-auth": "^4.23.0",

I have tried updating these packages to it's latest versions, but then adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma), this line fives compilation error,
But the current error I am facing is this error message,But the signIn works if I remove this adapter line,  
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
};

const hadnler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { hadnler as GET, hadnler as POST };

and here is my schema.prisma file
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Issue {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  // title String //varchar (191)
  title       String   @db.VarChar(225)
  description String   @db.Text //long text
  status      Status   @default(OPEN)
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @default(now())
}

model blog {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title       String   @db.VarChar(225)
  description String   @db.Text //long text
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @default(now())
}

enum Status {
  OPEN
  IN_PROGRESS
  CLOSED
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.Text
  access_token      String? @db.Text
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.Text
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}


What does "@/lib/prisma" export? You import prisma: is it an instance of PrismaClient?

everyone, my problem got solved once I ran, npx prisma generate.i was doing migration after I changed the schema, but running npx prisma generate solved the problem for me
